# Does django comments support pagination?

Tags: django, pagination, django-comments

I wonder is it possible to only display for example the 10 latest comments on the page. And then the user can click, on demand, if he wants to view more comments?

I was unsure what to search for therefore I ask it here instead.

I'm using the comment framework that is provided by Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its in the documentation. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/?from=olddocs

Comment: To be more clear you can autopaginate your comments and loop through them

Comment: I will be need to use `Comment.object.filter()` to get the comments I want to paginate right? Hmm, at the current implementation I do not need to get the comments manually from the view.

Comment: You can load them into your template using templatetags

Comment: By loading you mean, from the views load the comments and then pass it to the template?

Comment: Yes. In views depending how you have it set up you can set up a query from you comment model as an object and use it to pass to your template.